# Umbraco 7.2.8 form post results in an empty page

Tags: umbraco7

I've got a problem on the production server, the log file states:

```
WARN Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController - No physical template file was found for template Login
```

The login form-post results in an empty page.

The code works fine on my development machine. And before you ask, everything is uploaded on the server, the `web.configs` are the same (except `connectionstring` and `appsettings`).

Anyone with a similar problem?

The remote server is a shared environment, so I have no idea what type of modules and handlers are installed. I've asked for this from the hosting company.

// Carl